# What benefits for the developer does the Ruby language offer that C# does not have?

Tags: c#, ruby

What benefits for the developer does the Ruby language have that are not available in C# (preferably with code examples)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this articles: [What Is So Great About Ruby?](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/10/18/What-Is-So-Great-About-Ruby.aspx), also don't miss [Poor Man's Singleton Methods via Dynamic Wrappers in C#](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/10/poor-mans-singleton-methods-via-dynamic.html) as answer to first article.

Comment: +1 on that "What Is So Great About Ruby?" article. Excellent read.

Comment: Nick - thanks for the link. The article was really interesting and I can see why people rave over Ruby. Especially the mixins and duck typing.

Comment: Glad to share :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's extremely dynamic nature makes it very easy to create Domain Specific Languages. Ruby on Rails is the ne plus ultra of this aspect of Ruby as far as I know. RoR's ActiveMigrations is a DSL that takes a very difficult problem set and addresses it in a way that is easy to understand and to use. ActiveRecord, too.

Answer (score -1):

C# is a great language.  Ruby is an utterly remarkable one.

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)
```

Returns "3 minutes".  How many lines would this take in C#?

Ruby (and Rails, which actually implements that method) is about getting stuff done well, beautifully, expressively, and naturally.

Comment: You can do that in one line of C# too. Define an extension method `Minutes()` on `int` that returns a `DateTime`, then an extension method `FromNow()` on `DateTime`. That would let you do `(3).Minutes().FromNow()`. The `()` are kind of a drag, though. Unfortunately C# doesn't support extension properties, just methods.